# Floating Column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

For a multi-column layout, is it possible to show a figure in its own column, without interrupting the flow of text?

Here's the example:

```css
#col {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#col p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#col figure {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  break-before: column;
  break-after: column;
}

#col img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="col">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec nulla mauris. Quisque feugiat, metus ac volutpat laoreet.</p>
  <p>Aliquam euismod, sem sit amet elementum ultrices, enim sapien viverra enim, non bibendum ipsum velit nec tellus. Proin efficitur leo et leo feugiat.</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" height="100" />
  </figure>
  <p>Vivamus ut dui pulvinar, malesuada magna commodo, accumsan nisi. Duis imperdiet, libero sed facilisis lacinia, massa odio euismod orci, eget hendrerit erat mi vel risus.</p>
  <p>Sed a mi varius, fringilla mi eu, varius justo. Aliquam semper augue ut justo laoreet, at eleifend enim maximus. Fusce risus ligula, venenatis at augue vitae, maximus elementum orci. Nunc vel eleifend sem.</p>
  <p>Proin ac sem eu mi pretium consequat. Etiam elementum magna at felis convallis mattis. Donec molestie fringilla tempor. Nulla eros urna, aliquet non enim eget, gravida semper arcu.</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately there is a giant gap after the text before the figure. I would like the figure to show in its own column without interrupting the flow of text.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can float the figure!

```css
#col {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#col p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#col figure {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#col img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="col">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec nulla mauris. Quisque feugiat, metus ac volutpat laoreet.</p>
  <p>Aliquam euismod, sem sit amet elementum ultrices, enim sapien viverra enim, non bibendum ipsum velit nec tellus. Proin efficitur leo et leo feugiat.</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" height="100" />
  </figure>
  <p>Vivamus ut dui pulvinar, malesuada magna commodo, accumsan nisi. Duis imperdiet, libero sed facilisis lacinia, massa odio euismod orci, eget hendrerit erat mi vel risus.</p>
  <p>Sed a mi varius, fringilla mi eu, varius justo. Aliquam semper augue ut justo laoreet, at eleifend enim maximus. Fusce risus ligula, venenatis at augue vitae, maximus elementum orci. Nunc vel eleifend sem.</p>
  <p>Proin ac sem eu mi pretium consequat. Etiam elementum magna at felis convallis mattis. Donec molestie fringilla tempor. Nulla eros urna, aliquet non enim eget, gravida semper arcu.</p>
</div>
```

Now the figure can appear in its own column, and the text flows around it naturally.